# How to redirect with form validation in javascript to PHP webpage with MySQL query to another page

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have made a form which has validation technique using javascript
 (register.php), `location.href="storedata.php"` to redirect to page
 which has MySQL query in , from there I want to redirect to another
 page (`successful.php`).

Simplified Code is like this:

register.php

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function formValidate(){
    //FORM VALIDATION
    } 
   location.href="storedata.php";
    </script>
    <body>
    <form name="register" onsubmit="return formValidate()" method="post">
    //Form Values
    </form>
    </body>
```

storedata.php

```
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","UserPassDB");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Users (UserName, Email, Password, Gender)
    VALUES ('$_POST[duser]', '$_POST[demail]','$_POST[dpwd]',$_POST[gender] )");

    mysqli_close($con);


    header("Location: successful.php");
    exit();

    ?>
```

successful.php

```
<?php echo "Congratulations!!! you have been registered"; ?>
```

Earlier It was going good but after inserting 1 or 2 values to database, it just empties all fields of form. Can someone please tell me where I am wrong.
OR you can suggests any other way to redirecting to pages like this.

Comment: no body can understand what are you saying unless you make your explanations accurate!!!!

Comment: I understand that some people can't speak English well, but this is incomprehensible.

Comment: I want to redirect from a page which has a form which is validated with javascript and to redirect after validation, I want to fire sql query which I have written in PHP, then I want to redirect to page name successful.php which show you have been successfully registered.

Answer (score 0):

you have redirected your "register.php" page to "storedata.php", which is not correct, you need to submit your "register.php" page to "storedata.php", for that remove this line from your code

```
location.href="storedata.php";
```

after this give action to your form tag as "storedata.php" i.e.

```
<form name="register" onsubmit="return formValidate()" method="post" action="storedata.php">
```

Comment: If I do as you said, it will redirect directly to storedata.php without validating the form which is present on register.php page only. Is there any way to redirect register.php to storedata.php with validating all fields of form which is in register.php??? and thanks for suggestion :-)

Comment: i asked you to remove this line 
location.href="storedata.php"; from your code, which is actually directly redirecting your page to storedata.php and asked you to add form action in register.php file, so it will only redirect when form is submitted

Comment: Thanks :-)
Actually I was doing the same thing but it wasn't showing in database(as I was not refreshing database). So I changed my way to redirecting to other page and I was using javascript for validating and redirection both.